# Look for sleeping connections in node-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

Is there a way to show all sleeping connections in node-mysql (and preferably the query's these connections executed)?

Comment: Don't think it's possible, because `node-mysql` doesn't keep track of any connections that you created with `createConnection`. But if you see sleeping connections, are you sure you're ending them properly? Or, if you use pooling, are you returning them back to the pool once you're done?

Comment: Ye they were not ended properly. I didn't found a way to log all connections, but just checked all my code whether all query's we're being closed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Did not found a way to log connections in node-mysql.
Half solution; looked for unclosed connections in the project and used these sql statements to show open/sleeping connections and terminate them.

```
SHOW status
SHOW PROCESSLIST
KILL procesid
```